# Regex match line Z only if preceded by line X but not if preceded by line Y

Tags: regex

Let me preface this by saying that the text is fed in line by line.  Lookahead will NOT work.

So for the following I should be running two separate regex searches.

This is about as far as I got with the regex before my brain hurt:

Case 1:

```
(?<!Case 2.)[\s\S]*?This line should match\.
```

Case 2:

```
(?<!Case 1.)[\s\S]*?This line should match\.
```

The first regex search should return a successful match for every line which matches the text: "This line should match." after the line "Case 1." but before the line "Case 2." (bracketed [ ] here for clarity)

The second regex search should return a successful match for every line which matches the text: `"This line should match." after the line "Case 2." but before the line "Start of new sequence." (parenthetical ( ) here for clarity)

In the actual text the parenthesis and brackets are not there and the two different sets of lines are textually identical.

Text being searched:

```
Start of new sequence.
Random line(s).
Case 1.
Random line(s).
[This line should match.]
Random line(s).
[This line should match.]
Random line(s).
Case 2.
Random line(s).
(This line should match.)
Random line(s).
(This line should match.)
Random line(s).

Start of new sequence.
Random line(s).
Case 1.
Random line(s).
[This line should match.]
Random line(s).
[This line should match.]
Random line(s).
Case 2.
Random line(s).
(This line should match.)
Random line(s).
(This line should match.)
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you imagine a conditional match before (or after) a pattern you still don't have?
So if you receive the line, then you can match the pattern (with lookahead or any other construction).

Using lookahead I simply propose:

```
(?<=Case 1\.).*?(\[This line should match.\]).*?(?=Case 2\.)
```

and

```
(?<=Case 2\.).*?(\(This line should match.\)).*?(?=Start of new sequence\.)
```

[This](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3DCase%202%5C.).*%3F(%5C(This%20line%20should%20match.%5C)).*%3F(%3F%3DStart%20of%20new%20sequence%5C.)&test_string=Start%20of%20new%20sequence.%0ARandom%20line(s).%0ACase%201.%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A%5BThis%20line%20should%20match.%5D%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A%5BThis%20line%20should%20match.%5D%0ARandom%20line(s).%0ACase%202.%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A(This%20line%20should%20match.)%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A(This%20line%20should%20match.)%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A%0AStart%20of%20new%20sequence.%0ARandom%20line(s).%0ACase%201.%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A%5BThis%20line%20should%20match.%5D%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A%5BThis%20line%20should%20match.%5D%0ARandom%20line(s).%0ACase%202.%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A(This%20line%20should%20match.)%0ARandom%20line(s).%0A(This%20line%20should%20match.)&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=1&verbose=0) do the job for your example.

Comment: No this isn't really even close to what I'm trying to do.  Firstly, I can't use lookahead because i'm running this operation on a chat log as the information comes in.  When it reaches the line it should match it should be the last line that can be read.